# What language is the Russian segment ISS software written in?

Tags: iss, software, russia, computing, russian-segment

I have heard that the ISS uses a Russian coding language for some of the systems and subsystems on the Russian segment of the ISS. What is that coding language?

Comment: for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRAKON

Answer (score 5):

What I have seen of the code the Russians deliver to the Space Station trainer is written in C. These are the same engineers from Energia that write the Service Module software so I'm guessing they also use C. If the C is generated from [DRAKON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRAKON) I don't know. [Lua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)) is also used in the Russian simulator.